# Q: Hot to change Ip in request using tor-request npm

Tags: node.js, request, tor

i'm trying to change Ip by using tor
According to Tor-Request Documentation I should be able to do this simply by using

```
newTorSession
```

But ip not changing. What is wrong in my code?

```
var tr = require('tor-request');

requestIP();


tr.setTorAddress('localhost', 9050);



tr.newTorSession( (err) =>
    {
        console.log (err);
        requestIP();
        return;
    });
//console.log (tr.TorControlPort)

function requestIP() {
    tr.request('https://api.ipify.org', function (err, res, body) {
  if (!err && res.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log("Your public (through Tor) IP is: " + body);
  }
})
}
```

Answer (score 5):

From the [doc](https://github.com/talmobi/tor-request#optional-configuring-tor-enabling-the-controlport)

> You need to enable the Tor ControlPort if you want to programmatically
>   refresh the Tor session (i.e., get a new proxy IP address) without
>   restarting your Tor client.

so you need to follow these steps to enable ControlPort then pass that password to `tor-request`

```
tr.TorControlPort.password = 'PASSWORD'
```